# How to fix "UnsupportedOperationError: The command 'POST /session/:id/timeouts/async_script' was not found." e2e tests,Safari,protractor,selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, safari, angularjs-e2e, gulp-protractor

I am trying to run Protractor e2e tests on Selenium and Safari Version 12.1.1 (14607.2.6.1.1) for the AngularJS web application. Those tests are successfully running on Chrome with the Chrome web driver.

I have enabled Develop tab in Safari with "Allow Remote Automation" checked.

I've followed this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/testing_with_webdriver_in_safari tutorial in order to make sure that my safaridriver is enabled and that I have correct Selenium library version.

Info:
"protractor": "4.0.14",
"selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar"

I run it with "gulp e2e --browsers=safari". The Safari browser starts for a second and then shuts itself down. Error code I get is: Error: UnsupportedOperationError: The command 'POST /session/04A32527-1B80-4171-BB56-4B169A75855E/timeouts/async_script' was not found. Error code 100.

I found that this command since Safari 12 should be supported.